# Skipping long lines at free-museum days in Paris

Tags: paris, museums

In Paris, many museums are free on the first Sunday of each month. Thus the lines for museum entry can be extremely long. Is it possible to skip through the line if I bought a ticket in advance?

I ask because the security line to enter the Louvre is usually quite long and visitors who pre-purchased tickets can skip to the front of the security line, so I'm wondering if this applies on free-entry days (as it can be worth my money to save time in the line).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost all online tour / ticket purchases have a blanked-out option for 'free Sundays' - there's no way to do it through them.

From some research, it appears there are multiple entrances to queue at, and some people report [having good luck at the Carrousel du Louvre entrance](http://liliansg.hubpages.com/hub/Paris-The-Louvre), only waiting 20 minutes.

Almost everyone reports that even if you get in quickly, it depends what you're after.  You may be in a MOB of people trying to see the Mona Lisa, or if you have other tastes, one for example reports being alone in the 18th century Scandinavian art room on a free Sunday.

From all reports, unless you are prepared to get there really early, and accept that there may be mobs of families and screaming children (especially if it's a wet day outside), try to go during the week instead.  The fee you pay will be worth it, and then you can use one of the skip-the-queue options with your ticket.

Comment: +1 "there may be mobs of families and screaming children". From a couple of personal experiences at the Louvre, the sheer amount of people and noise on Free Sunday's really makes it worth it to buy a ticket during the week and avoid that mess.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the current, sixteenth edition of *The Rough Guide to Paris* and is concerning the Louvre:

> The main entrance is via the Pyramide, but you'll find shorter queues
>   at two different entrances: the one near the Arc du Carrousel (which
>   can also be accessed from 99 rue de Rivoli and from the #1 platform of
>   the Palais Royal Musée du Louvre métro stop); and at the Porte des
>   Lions entrance, just east of the Pont Royal (though this is sometimes
>   closed, so it's best to phone ahead to check).
>
> If you've already got a ticket or a museum pass you can join the
>   fast-track queue at the Pyramide. Disabled access is via the
>   futuristic sinking column in the middle of the Pyramide; entry is free
>   to registered disabled visitors plus one companion.